# How to insert record where is not exists and if exists ignore it by using mysql or knex and express js

Tags: mysql, express, knex.js

I want to check my data base if the value already exists then don't add the same value and if not exists add this new value .

my code

```
router.post('/additem', function(req, res, next){
  db('types').insert({type_name: req.body.getypename}).where('type_name', '!=', req.body.getypename).then(()=>{
     res.redirect('/additem?success=1')
  }).catch((err)=>{ res.redirect('/additem?'+err) })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Using `.count()` would be one way to check for the existence of the record before you add it. See the below function `countTypeNameRec` as an example of that.

The below function `addTypeNameRec` then puts the count & insert together, first checking the count of records, then if it's zero, adding the record.

See [the Knex .count() reference](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-count) for additional details about using `.count()`. (For large unindexed tables, using `select * where xxx limit 1` would probably be a better performance choice.)

**A Second Method:**
I assume that it's a hard rule that you can't have 'type' table records with duplicate 'type_name' field values. If that's the case, then making that field a primary key via your SQL table definition in your db (or creating a unique index on the table for the field) will also prevent users from creating duplicate records. In that case the `.insert()` statement will throw an error on a duplicate record. But it is a little messy to interpret the error if you want to give the user an understandable 'Value already exists' error message. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684205/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-the-types-of-knex-errors/52753070#52753070) is a discussion on that issue.

If you don't care about returning the user an ugly raw database error which they probably won't understand, then you can use this second method in a simplistic fashion and just call the `insertTypeNameRec` function from the routing code instead of the `addTypeNameRec` function (skipping the count check).

**The Code**

```
// count the records
//
function countTypeNameRec(input_type_name) {
   return db('types')
    .count('*')
    .where('type_name', input_type_name)
    .then((data)=>{
            return data[0].count
        })
}

// insert a new record
//
function insertTypeNameRec(input_type_name) {
   return db('types')
    .insert({type_name: input_type_name})
}

// Combine the count & insert - the real goal
//
function addTypeNameRec(input_type_name) {

   return countTypeNameRec(input_type_name)
     .then((rec_count) => {
        if (rec_count===0) {
            insertTypeNameRec(input_type_name) 
        } else {
            // we can return an already exists error from here
        }
     })
}

// Web routing code
//
router.post('/additem', function(req, res, next){

   const input_type_name = req.body.getypename;
   // we could validate our input here

   // for simplistic second method - call insertTypeNameRec() here instead
   return addTypeNameRec(input_type_name)
      .then(()=>{
            res.redirect('/additem?success=1')
       })
       .catch((err)=>{ 
            res.redirect('/additem?'+err) 
       })
})

// disclaimer: this code has not been tested
```

**A Freebie** (i.e. comments on things you didn't ask about) ... I tend to try to separate my capabilities into the smallest pieces/functions that I can. Then it becomes super simple to troubleshoot and test each piece. I especially try to separate the code at the database & communications tiers. Then it's easy to stub out the web requests, and test them separately from the other server processing.